# How to separate Identityserver4 frontend and backend

Tags: c#, .net, angular, identityserver4

A third party will be implementing my script that will inject a button on their site which will open an angular2 application in a new window hosted on my server.

The angular2 application will then authenticate the user using identityserver4 also hosted on my server but will be on a different subdomain.

The user will then get some options to do different things in the angular2 application but eventually the JWT will be passed down to the third party.

---

So what I want to do is seperate the views from [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/QuickstartIdentityServer) identityserver4 project to a separate angular2 project that will be on a different subdomain from the identityserver.

So my problem is how do I get the JWT from a javascript application that runs on sub1.mydomain.com from IdentityServer4 that runs on sub2.mydomain.com which validates the client/username/password and returns a JWT ?

Is this even possible ?

Edit:
Tried to visualize[image: Tried To Visualize]

Answer (score 0):

Well that should be possible. As you haven't shown any code, it is a bit hard to help you with specifics.

If you try to follow the excellent guide they have made [IdentityServer4_jsclient](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html)

They will show you how to setup a seperat javascript client. This client will be your Angular2.0 application.

Then you can either use the templates they have provided in the link you have mentioned, to get a login flow. Or you can code your own login flow application, that will give the users a way to login. Look at their login flow in the quick start guide and try to understand how it works. You should be able to mimic this behaviour with a SPA application.

Comment: but I need the "login flow" to be my angular2 application on a separate subdomain from the identityserver.

Comment: @user3621898 Why do you wan't your login flow (angular2 app) to be on another subdomain than the identityserver? It should also be possible. You have to look through their quickstart flow. Get an understanding of the steps necessary to login, and then replicate them in your angular2 app. Using ajax calls instead of page changes.

Comment: Because plenty of other applications will be using the identityserver and lots of logic not related to the identityserver will be present in the angular2 app so I want to separate them as much as possible.